# Can't understand what multiplexers do in CPU datapath

Tags: multiplexer, cpu

I'm currently learning about data path in a CPU and having a hard time understanding the functionality of G,L, H parts in the following image. Why have those parts been used there?

[image]

Comment: You know what a multiplexer does in general?

Comment: Yes..I can understand that the multiplexer in D selects PC+4 or computed address and set it to PC..In other words, I know what a multiplexer is..What I can't understand is why they are used in **G** and **L** places..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**G multiplexer:** Selects the second argument to the ALU. Possible values are another register's value or the immediate value of the instruction.

**L multiplexer:** Selects the value to write into the destination register. Possible values are the value of the addressed RAM register or the result from the ALU.

**H shifter:** Multiplies the immediate value of the instruction by 4, as the PC needs.